# Php call function in other as C# and Java

Tags: php

I'am developing a website, and I'd like to know if there's a way to call a function as child from other

Ex: MyClass::functionParent()::FunctionChild();

I'm suing static mathod

I already tried using this

```
public static function something(){
    $name = function(){
       //to do
    };
}
```

but didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP it's bad practice to use static methods, because writing unit tests is quite "impossible". Here is an example without static methods:

```
class MySubClass
{
    public function childFunction()
    {
        return "hello";
    }
}

class MyClass
{
    public function something()
    {
        return new MySubClass();
    }
}

$object = new MyClass();

echo $object->something()->childFunction();
```

Comment: O thnak you  it's a pitty php  isn't that  good to use static method but anyway your answer helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

if you want to call a function which is located in same class you can do this

```
    class Myclass{
        public function a(){
            // your code
        }
        public function b(){
             $this->a();
        }
    }
```